# Conditional builder pattern with dynamic parameter list

Tags: java, design-patterns, builder

I have found Joshua Bloch builder pattern, its famous NutritionFacts example. Now I would like this builder to build two types of NutritionFacts. So lets say instead of:

```
NutritionFacts cocaCola = new NutritionFacts.Builder().
  calories(100).sodium(35).carbohydrate(27).build();
```

I would like to have something like that:

```
NutritionFactsA a = new NutritionFacts.Builder<NutritionFactsA>...().
  calories(100).build(); //.sodium(35).carbohydrate(27) - these are not possible to be set, when I write NutritionFactsA I cannot see these parameters

NutritionFactsB b = new NutritionFacts.Builder<NutritionFactsB>(240, 8).
  .sodium(35).build(); //here I have set only sodium value, I cannot set anything
```

So is it possible in Java7 and how to do that?

Comment: Why not `new NutritionFactsA.Builder` and `new NutritionFactsB.Builder`?

Comment: @Tunaki I agree, you should have separate builders in this case, instead of some complicated logic based on generics, remember Keep It Simple

Comment: Ok I guess I will have something like NutritionFacts.BuilderA and NutritionFactsBuilderB, the backgroud is creation of different parameter classes. Instead of having methods with 15 parameters I will have one parameter built by chosen builder. Every method have different parameters so I want to have couple of builders.